# Regular Expression for Bit Strings Divisible by 4

Tags: regex, math, binary, bitstring

I am newbie to Regular Expression.

In one of my homework problem, I have been ask to write the regular expression of  following.

```
The set of all bit strings (i.e. strings over alphabet {0,1}) that are divisible by 4.
```

Now, I am not getting how should I start to achieve solution. How to find bits divisible by 4?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
/^(1[01]*00|0)$/
```

A one followed by any number of ones and/or zeroes, ending in two zeroes, or just a single zero.

**EDIT:** If you don't mind leading zeroes, this will also work:

```
/^(?:[01]*0)?0$/
```